# Tkinter scroll wheel does not scroll down?

Tags: python, tkinter

As title claims, my tkinter scroll wheel doesnt seem to go down, does anyone know why? This is currently very messy as its just a small copy i made to solve a bigger problem

```
def update_scroll_region(event):
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
                  
# Function to send a message
def send_message():
    message = entry.get()
    if message:
        add_user_message(message)
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        receive_random_message()
        canvas.yview_moveto(1.0)  # Scroll to the bottom when sending a message

# Function to simulate receiving a random message
def receive_random_message():
    random_message = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=random.randint(5, 50)))
    add_other_message(random_message)
    canvas.yview_moveto(1.0)  # Scroll to the bottom when receiving a message

# Function to add a user message label
def add_user_message(message):
    user_label = tk.Label(chat_labels_frame, text="You:")
    user_label.pack(anchor="e")
    label = tk.Label(chat_labels_frame, text=message, bg="lightblue", anchor="e", padx=5, pady=5, wraplength=250)
    label.pack(anchor="e")
    user_messages.append(label)

# Function to add an other person's message label
def add_other_message(message):
    other_label = tk.Label(chat_labels_frame, text="Other Person:")
    other_label.pack(anchor="w")
    label = tk.Label(chat_labels_frame, text=message, bg="lightgreen", anchor="w", padx=5, pady=5, wraplength=250)
    label.pack(anchor="w")
    other_messages.append(label)

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a frame to hold the chat interface
frame = tk.Frame(root,height=500,width=300)
frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
canvas.pack()

chat_labels_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=chat_labels_frame, anchor="nw")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.place(x=350,y=0,height=200)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frame.bind("<Configure>", update_scroll_region)

# Create an entry widget for typing messages
entry = tk.Entry(frame,width=50)
entry.place(x=0,y=220)
send_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Send", command=send_message)
send_button.place(x=300,y=220)

user_messages = []
other_messages = []

# Start with a random initial message
receive_random_message()

# Run the Tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

This is just making a simple 'text message' gui that allows a user to send a message and sends a random string backwards

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` event on `chat_labels_frame` instead of `frame`.

Comment: cheers @acw1668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, the *scrollregion* of the canvas need to be updated whenever the internal frame `chat_labels_frame` is resized, not `frame`.  So the event `<Configure>` should be bound on `chat_labels_frame` instead of `frame`:

```py
chat_labels_frame.bind("<Configure>", update_scroll_region)
```